# @IBInspectable property doesn't show up in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have a class like this, and this IB doesn't show the property `foo1` in inspection pane.

```
@IBDesignable
final class Foo: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var bar1 = CGFloat(0) 
}
```

What's wrong?

(Xcode 10.1)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why, but explicit property type expression fixes the problem.

```
@IBDesignable
final class Foo: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var bar1 = CGFloat(0)   // No work. 
    @IBInspectable var bar2: CGFloat = 0   // Works!
}
```

I really don't know why one form doesn't work while the other works.
I hope Apple to fix this ASAP.

Comment: A strange requirement that seems necessary at the moment, `@IBInspectable var bar = UIColor.red` will not work where as `@IBInspectable var bar: UIColor = .red` will. If anyone else is having issues I strongly recommend checking that you have denoted the type.

Comment: I'm following all of this. Still not working. `@IBInspectable var nestedStackAxis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis = .vertical {`